# Border on element inside a single image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I'm struggling on a problem.
I have to put a border on element inside an image(I can't put an image due to reputation under 10) but that border should have the same width and height of that element.It should be responsive.I write the code based on bootstrap media screen resolution but when I reduced my page the wide becomes small at some specific screen resolution.That's the code.Thanks.

```
<div class="parent">
    <img />
    <span class="makeBorder"></span>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.makeBorder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 23px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 83%;
    height: 83%;
}
```

What I finally do:

```
<div class="customClass"><img /></div>

.customClass{outline:1px solid red;outline-offset:-18px;}
```

Comment: Try using media queries specific to when it begins to look weird. Then you can create css rules that only exist when the window is a certain size.

Comment: I tried to do that and leave it because I have noticed that when I specify a code for screen (max-width: 739px) it not working when I reduce the screen equals to 729px and so on. That why i tried to use percent width and height based on parent size but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hereby use a button on the image and it correctly work.Some of css property are no useful in this example denoted by //.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div{
                background:url("1.jpg") no-repeat;
                background-size:contain;//
                height:500px;//height of div
                width:500px;
                }
                button{
                height:50px;
                width:70px;
                outline:red solid 4px;
                margin:20px 20px;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button >Hello</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks I have tried it but not doing what I want.Maybe I will try to make it 2 images and put a border on that second image so that it will be the same on all screen media

Comment: can u explain it more

Comment: Hi @sandeep_1994, I was talking about creating 1 div with a background image and inside that called an image avec img tag and align it inside and then put a border on that image tag :    <div class="backgroundImage"><img /></div>. Finally I didn't do it because I was facing the same problem.So I used one div and inside that div I put an image tag and then used outline property on it.To mimic a responsive, for each screen media I played on the size of outline-offset. (I don't know how to put the code on this comment so I edited my first one on top). (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div{
            height:500px;
            width:500px;
            position:absolute;
            }
            button{
            position:absolute;
            height:50px;
            width:70px;
            outline:red solid 4px;
            margin:20px 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="1.jpg">
        </div>
        <button >Hello</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

use this code if you want to use 2 images then provide background image

```
  z-index=-1;
```

use the above positioning property;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="/path/to/img/png" class="img-responsive" />  // Here I added a class img-responsive
    <span class="makeBorder"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.makeBorder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%; // Here I use percentage instead of pixels
    left: 23%; // Here I use percentage instead of pixels
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 83%;
    height: 83%;
}
```

**NOTE:** The point I want to make is use **percentages** instead of pixels so that your work/html become responsive !!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.makeBorder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 81px;
  left: 83px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 55px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBnmmAWOlqD-8ZjLvlkXoz0sSMOd7DiA5paUl7Ug2VBjXnnqKaHw" />
  <span class="makeBorder"></span>
</div>
```

i suppose this is what you want to do